# SMS texts hanging

Tags: macos, performance, sms, text

I have an iPhone, iPad and a Macbook. All are interconnected for iMessage and I can use my Macbook for SMS texting as well via forwarding. Lately, my SMS texts, only, are not going through and I get a red exclamation point and an undeliverable message. This tends to occur when I send a longer message. One liners go through not problem. The line on top that shows the progression of the message being sent will move rapidly toward the end, then just hangs. It will do this for a minute until it says undeliverable. If I hit retry, sometimes it will go through, others not. If I send the message to myself on email it goes through fine, but not to another person's non-iPhone.

I reset my router incase that was the problem. I turned off messaging and turned it back on. I turned off forwarding (still happened on just phone) and turned it back on. Same thing. Both devices.

I just posted another question about mail hanging too, and it seems both problems started around the same time.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the Apple Article on troubleshooting SMS? It has a few steps that ends with "call the carrier"

Comment: I saw that. My internet and phone (data) are working fine though. Its not a matter of coverage. I'm online fine, I'm using both data and internet and this is happening so it couldn't be the carrier since they are not the same.

Comment: @gracey209 actually it could be. SMS's send from iMessage using your iPhone and its carrier signal, not the internet.

Comment: Not when I send an sms from my Macbook, unless I'm toggled into my iPhones data, which i'm not. So on my phone I'm using my phone company's data and on my laptop I'm using wireless internet by a different provider. Its happening in both scenarios is my point.